# passing map containing user defined object as value to play framework2 scala template

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using play framework v2.2 and trying to pass a map to a scala template.  The map has a string as its key and a user defined object as its value.  My controller is in Java  - the template is in Scala.

**Controller**:

```
 Map<String, UDObject> myMap = new HashMap<String, UDObject>();
 UDObject ud1 = new UDObject(a,b,c);  
 myMap.put("abcd", ud1);
 return ok(index.render(myMap));
```

**Index.scala.html Template**:

```
@(myMap: Map[String, UDObject])
```

When I try reload/eclipse or use play run/start - I get a compilation error complaining that the template could not find the user defined object UDObject. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the fully qualified name in the declaration of the parameters in the Play template, e.g:

```
@(myMap: Map[String, com.example.UDObject])
```

Unfortunately there is no way to `import` it, so anything that isn't in the model, view or Scala namespace must use the full name.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add this import for all your templates as well.

`templatesImport ++= Seq("com.example.UDObject")`

Now you don't need to use the fully qualified name of your class.

Comment: tried adding it - saw the note on the play framework site as well but for some reason, its not working for me (I reloaded/ran eclipse and ran clean as well)